# Android NDK and Card.io

Tags: android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, card.io

Hi I'm trying to modify the source code for card.io for Android but I'm having issues simply getting the sample app to run.

I followed all of the instructions listed on [github](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-source) perfectly and everything seems to go on without a hitch but I keep getting this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':card.io:buildNative'.
> Process 'command '/Applications/Android Studio.app/android-ndk-r10e/ndk-build'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

There have been a few posts about this error but the solutions all seem to be caused by modifications users have made to the gradle whereas I haven't modified any of the source.

Here is my local.properties folder:

```
sdk.dir=/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk
ndk.dir=/Applications/Android Studio.app/android-ndk-r10e
```

here is the gradle file (untouched from the source)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

def getBuildVersion = { ->
    "git describe --match=*[0-9]*.[0-9]*.*[0-9] --tags --dirty --always".execute().text.trim()
}

ext {
    sdkDir = android.plugin.sdkFolder
    ndkDir = android.plugin.ndkFolder
    adb = new File("${sdkDir}/platform-tools/adb")

    build_time = new Date().format("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss Z")
    build_year = new Date().format("yyyy")
    product_name = "card.io-Android-SDK"
    product_version = getBuildVersion()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 21

        buildConfigField "String", "PRODUCT_NAME", "\"${product_name}\""
        buildConfigField "String", "PRODUCT_VERSION", "\"${product_version}\""
        buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"${build_time}\""

        testApplicationId 'io.card.development'
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = []
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-build.cfg'
        }
    }

    task cleanNative(type: Exec, description: 'Clean JNI object files') {
        commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build",
                '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath,
                'clean'
    }
    clean.dependsOn cleanNative

    task buildNative(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
        commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build",
                '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath,
                '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors(),
                'all'
    }
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn buildNative
    }

    tasks.whenTaskAdded { theTask ->
        if (theTask.name == "packageReleaseJniLibs"
                || theTask.name == "packageDebugJniLibs") {
            theTask.dependsOn(buildNative)
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile "com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.2.1"
}

// TODO remove the variant specific stuff from below - card.io doesn't have flavors

// ----------------  Javadocs ---------------

// More info here: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Javadoc.html
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    def buildType = variant.buildType.name
    def variantName = variant.baseName


    if (buildType.equalsIgnoreCase("debug")) {
        return;
    }

    task "${variantName}Doc"(dependsOn: "compile${variantName.capitalize()}Java", type: Javadoc) {
        description = "Generates javadoc for build $name"
        destinationDir = new File(destinationDir, variantName)
        source = variant.javaCompile.source
        def variantCompiledClassesDir = file("${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/${variant.dirName}/")
        classpath = files(
                variant.javaCompile.classpath,
                variantCompiledClassesDir,
                project.plugins.findPlugin("com.android.library").bootClasspath
        )

        include 'io/card/payment/*.java'

        // More info on options here: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/external/javadoc/StandardJavadocDocletOptions.html
        // all of these options were copied from the ant build.  I don't know what half these options actually do.
        options.docTitle("<h1>card.io Android SDK</h1>")
        options.bottom("<i>Copyright &#169; 2012-${build_year} PayPal, Inc. All Rights Reserved.</i>")
        options.windowTitle("card.io Android SDK")
        options.author(true)
        options.version(true)
        options.use(true)
        options.setMemberLevel(JavadocMemberLevel.PUBLIC)

        // enables links to Java 7 docs
        options.links("http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/")
        // enables links to Android docs.
        options.linksOffline("http://d.android.com/reference", "${sdkDir}/docs/reference")
    }

    task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: "${variantName}Doc") {
        classifier = 'javadoc'
        from releaseDoc.destinationDir
    }

    // ------- MavenCentral publishing

    task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
        classifier = 'sources'
        from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    }

    artifacts {
        archives javadocJar, sourcesJar
    }

    signing {
        sign configurations.archives
    }

    // these should be specified in the gradle.properties file as:
    // systemProp.sonatypeUsername=xxxxxxx
    // systemProp.sonatypePassword=yyyyyyy
    def sonatypeUsername = System.properties.containsKey('sonatypeUsername') ? System.properties['sonatypeUsername'] : ''
    def sonatypePassword = System.properties.containsKey('sonatypePassword') ? System.properties['sonatypePassword'] : ''

    uploadArchives {
        doFirst {
            println "***"
            println "uploading archives using username: '" + sonatypeUsername + "'"
            println "***"
        }

        repositories {
            mavenDeployer {
                beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }

                repository(url: 'https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/') {
                    authentication(userName: sonatypeUsername, password: sonatypePassword)
                }

                pom.setArtifactId 'android-sdk'

                pom.project {
                    name 'android-sdk'
                    groupId = 'io.card'
                    version = "${product_version}"
                    packaging 'aar'
                    description 'This is card.io\'s SDK for Android.'
                    url 'https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-source/'

                    scm {
                        url 'scm:git@github.com:card-io/card.io-Android-source.git'
                        connection 'scm:git@github.com:card-io/card.io-Android-source.git'
                        developerConnection 'scm:git@github.com:card-io/card.io-Android-source.git'
                    }

                    developers {
                        developer {
                            id 'brateman'
                            name 'Jeff Brateman'
                        }
                    }

                    licenses {
                        license {
                            name 'MIT'
                            url 'http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT'
                            distribution 'repo'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I tried other versions of the ndk with no luck. Really confused here! Any help is really appreciated

EDIT: here is the stack trace and some extra info

--info:

```
> Total time: 14.844 secs Arjunas-MacBook-Air-3:card.io-Android-source
> Arjuna$ ./gradlew clean assembleDebug --info Starting Build Settings
> evaluated using settings file
> '/Users/Arjuna/Documents/workspace/card.io-Android-source/settings.gradle'.
> Projects loaded. Root project using build file
> '/Users/Arjuna/Documents/workspace/card.io-Android-source/build.gradle'.
> Included projects: [root project 'card.io-Android-source', project
> ':SampleApp', project ':card.io'] Evaluating root project
> 'card.io-Android-source' using build file
> '/Users/Arjuna/Documents/workspace/card.io-Android-source/build.gradle'.
> Evaluating project ':SampleApp' using build file
> '/Users/Arjuna/Documents/workspace/card.io-Android-source/SampleApp/build.gradle'.
> Evaluating project ':card.io' using build file
> '/Users/Arjuna/Documents/workspace/card.io-Android-source/card.io/build.gradle'.
> All projects evaluated. Selected primary task 'clean' from project :
> Selected primary task 'assembleDebug' from project : file or directory
> '/Users/Arjuna/Documents/workspace/card.io-Android-source/SampleApp/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug',
> not found Tasks to be executed: [task ':SampleApp:clean', task
> ':card.io:cleanNative', task ':card.io:clean', task
> ':SampleApp:preBuild', task ':SampleApp:compileDebugNdk', task
> ':SampleApp:preDebugBuild', task ':SampleApp:checkDebugManifest', task
> ':SampleApp:preReleaseBuild', task ':card.io:compileLint', task
> ':card.io:copyReleaseLint', task ':card.io:mergeReleaseProguardFiles',
> task ':card.io:buildNative', task ':card.io:preBuild', task
> ':card.io:compileReleaseNdk', task ':card.io:packageReleaseJniLibs',
> task ':card.io:packageReleaseRenderscript', task
> ':card.io:preReleaseBuild', task ':card.io:checkReleaseManifest', task
> ':card.io:prepareReleaseDependencies', task
> ':card.io:compileReleaseRenderscript', task
> ':card.io:generateReleaseResValues', task
> ':card.io:generateReleaseResources', task
> ':card.io:packageReleaseResources', task
> ':card.io:compileReleaseAidl', task
> ':card.io:generateReleaseBuildConfig', task
> ':card.io:generateReleaseAssets', task ':card.io:mergeReleaseAssets',
> task ':card.io:processReleaseManifest', task
> ':card.io:processReleaseResources', task
> ':card.io:generateReleaseSources', task ':card.io:compileReleaseJava',
> task ':card.io:proguardRelease', task ':card.io:bundleRelease', task
> ':SampleApp:prepareCardIoAndroidSourceCardIoUnspecifiedLibrary', task
> ':SampleApp:prepareDebugDependencies', task
> ':SampleApp:compileDebugAidl', task
> ':SampleApp:compileDebugRenderscript', task
> ':SampleApp:generateDebugBuildConfig', task
> ':SampleApp:generateDebugAssets', task ':SampleApp:mergeDebugAssets',
> task ':SampleApp:generateDebugResValues', task
> ':SampleApp:generateDebugResources', task
> ':SampleApp:mergeDebugResources', task
> ':SampleApp:processDebugManifest', task
> ':SampleApp:processDebugResources', task
> ':SampleApp:generateDebugSources', task ':SampleApp:compileDebugJava',
> task ':SampleApp:preDexDebug', task ':SampleApp:dexDebug', task
> ':SampleApp:processDebugJavaRes', task
> ':SampleApp:validateDebugSigning', task ':SampleApp:packageDebug',
> task ':SampleApp:zipalignDebug', task ':SampleApp:assembleDebug', task
> ':card.io:copyDebugLint', task ':card.io:mergeDebugProguardFiles',
> task ':card.io:preDebugBuild', task ':card.io:checkDebugManifest',
> task ':card.io:prepareDebugDependencies', task
> ':card.io:compileDebugAidl', task ':card.io:compileDebugRenderscript',
> task ':card.io:generateDebugBuildConfig', task
> ':card.io:generateDebugAssets', task ':card.io:mergeDebugAssets', task
> ':card.io:generateDebugResValues', task
> ':card.io:generateDebugResources', task
> ':card.io:packageDebugResources', task
> ':card.io:processDebugManifest', task
> ':card.io:processDebugResources', task
> ':card.io:generateDebugSources', task ':card.io:compileDebugJava',
> task ':card.io:processDebugJavaRes', task ':card.io:packageDebugJar',
> task ':card.io:compileDebugNdk', task ':card.io:packageDebugJniLibs',
> task ':card.io:packageDebugLocalJar', task
> ':card.io:packageDebugRenderscript', task ':card.io:bundleDebug', task
> ':card.io:assembleDebug'] :SampleApp:clean (Thread[main,5,main])
> started. :SampleApp:clean Executing task ':SampleApp:clean'
> (up-to-date check took 0.001 secs) due to:   Task has not declared any
> outputs. :SampleApp:clean (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.034
> secs. :card.io:cleanNative (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
> :card.io:cleanNative Executing task ':card.io:cleanNative' (up-to-date
> check took 0.0 secs) due to:   Task has not declared any outputs.
> Starting process 'command '/Applications/Android
> Studio.app/android-ndk-r10e/ndk-build''. Working directory:
> /Users/Arjuna/Documents/workspace/card.io-Android-source/card.io
> Command: /Applications/Android Studio.app/android-ndk-r10e/ndk-build
> -C /Users/Arjuna/Documents/workspace/card.io-Android-source/card.io/src/main/jni
> clean Successfully started process 'command '/Applications/Android
> Studio.app/android-ndk-r10e/ndk-build'' usage: dirname path make:
> /Users/Arjuna/build/core/build-local.mk: No such file or directory
> make: *** No rule to make target
> `/Users/Arjuna/build/core/build-local.mk'.  Stop. :card.io:cleanNative
> FAILED :card.io:cleanNative (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took
> 0.107 secs.
> 
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> 
> * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':card.io:cleanNative'.
> > Process 'command '/Applications/Android Studio.app/android-ndk-r10e/ndk-build'' finished with non-zero exit
> value 2
```

--stacktrace

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':card.io:cleanNative'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Applications/Android Studio.app/android-ndk-r10e/ndk-build'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:365)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecAction.execute(DefaultExecAction.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.AbstractExecTask.exec(AbstractExecTask.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:579)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:562)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 47 more
```

Comment: You have the ndk installed in the directory you mention?  Have you tried running the gradle build command with `--info` to get more output?

Comment: Yes the ndk is in the correct directory. I posted the results of --info and --stacktrace in case anyone can make something of it.

Comment: It's complaining about a missing file: `/Users/Arjuna/build/core/build-local.mk`.  Why is it looking for that file?